# Turning off "Drag Fill Series" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am ideally looking to only turn off the drag fill series functionality.

I only want the user of my sheet to be able to drag COPY down.

I turned the feature off in settings, which disable ALL drag downs. I would be happy with that, but of course this only works in my own Excel settings, other users of the sheet will still be able too in the context of their settings.

I am wondering if there is a way in VBA to turnoff the fill series features or disable the drag feature entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest challenge you will face is Macro Security on the individual machines. If they are not set to run Macros this will keep this from running.

You can use the following in VBA to disable Cell Drag and Drop when the workbook opens.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub
```

In order to avoid making people angry, you should turn it back on when the workbook closes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub
```

You can use the `IF` statement to check if the feature is turned on off/on to ensure you return it to the original state. The biggest challenge you will face is Macro Security on the individual machines. If they are not set to run Macros this will keep this from running.

Comment: When closing the workbook down, I am getting an error box emerging: Compile Error, Ambiguous name detected: BeforeClose   .  I have saved both your macro's in "This Workbook" macro sheet as opposed to an individual sheet macro.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
End Sub                           how does this macro know that the workbook is closing?

Comment: Excel knows and executes the event handler/subroutine automatically when the event occurs. Also, the declaration should be *Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(**Cancel As Boolean**) ... End Sub*